# Build xcframework using Aggregated Targets in xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, frameworks, aggregate

I was trying to create an aggregate framework in Xcode 12.4  My run script is :- [image: Added script]

but getting the error when i compile. can anyone help me on this .[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could delete the derived data and try once again.
ANSSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in more than one place. You can recheck extensions and verify whether it's repeated in any extensions.